# Unable to Cast Object "type" on "type" c#

Tags: c#, casting

I'm working to the server-side of my game, it's almost finished but today I had a problem... This game is based on 2 modalities, touchdown and deathmatch, at the end of the game the server have to know the results. It's an online game. When I end the match or a player get out, the server crashes, it should not be, it had just to return to the room. It gives me the following error:

```
[ERROR]: Unable to cast object of type 'B3S.Core.Data.GameScore' to type 'B3S.Core.Data.TDGameScore'.
   in B3S.Core.Data.Player.SetNewTDStats(Boolean win)
   in B3S.Core.Data.Room.BroadcastBriefing(Boolean result)
   in B3S.Core.Data.Room.<BeginResult>d__2b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace ---
   in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__1(Object state)
   in System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   in System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   in System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   in System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Could anyone help me?!

This is the source of B3S.Core.Data.GameScore :

```
public class GameScore
    {
        public DateTime JoinTime { get; set; }
        public uint TotalPoints { get; set; }

        public virtual uint CalculateEXP()
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

This is the source of B3S.Core.Data.TDGameScore:

```
public class TDGameScore : GameScore
{
    public uint TDScore { get; set; }
    public uint TDAssists { get; set; }

    public uint Kills { get; set; }
    public uint KillAssists { get; set; }
    public uint Offense { get; set; }
    public uint OffenseAssists { get; set; }
    public uint Defense { get; set; }
    public uint DefenseAssists { get; set; }
    public uint Recovery { get; set; }

    public override uint CalculateEXP()
    {
        var ts = DateTime.Now - JoinTime;
        if (ts.TotalSeconds < 0 || TotalPoints == 0)
            return 0;
        return (uint)ts.TotalSeconds / 4 + (TDScore * 15) + (100 * TotalPoints / (500 + 2 * TotalPoints) * 14);
    }
}
```

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: I recommend that you use a different namespace name that doesn't start with a derogatory word that might offend some people.

Comment: I have to use the TDGameScore because it's even the GameScore but has other attribs 'cuz it is for TouchDown gamemode.

Comment: I'm referring to your namespace name `FagNet.Core.Data.GameScore `. The first word (at least in America) is offensive to a lot of people.

Comment: I will edit it as soon as possible,
BTW if I remove the : GameScore after TDGameScore, I Get lot of errors like : Impossible to convert type "FagNet.Core.Data.GameScore" to "FagNet.Core.Data.TDGameScore"

NB : Project's name is now B3S.Core

Answer (score 1):

The TDGameScore is a subclass (derived class) of GameScore.
Most likely, you pass around an instance of GameScore which is NOT a TDGameScore. You have to check when that problematic instance is created and why it is not of a correct subtype.

Comment: I don't know how to edit for making work...
I tried a lot of things but always the same error.